# What are the 3rd party libs which CKE5 uses internally?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

We are evaluating the ckeditor 5 and need the following information -

Can we get some pointers around the 3rd party libs which CKE5 uses internally ?

I tried searching the cke5 API docs (link below) online but couldn't find anything useful.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

The license shines a light on it and it can be found here:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Particularly this list explains it:

> The following libraries are included in CKEditor under the MIT license:
>
> color-convert - Copyright (c) 2011-2016 Heather Arthur fayearthur@gmail.com, copyright (c) 2016-2021 Josh Junon josh@junon.me (MIT license).
> color-parse - Copyright (c) 2015 Dmitry Ivanov (MIT license).
> lodash - Copyright (c) JS Foundation and other contributors https://js.foundation/. Based on Underscore.js, copyright Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors http://underscorejs.org/.
> marked - Copyright (c) Christopher Jeffrey. (MIT License)
> turndown - turndown is copyright © Dom Christie and released under the MIT license.
> turndown-plugin-gfm - turndown-plugin-gfm is copyright © Dom Christie and released under the MIT license.
> vanilla-colorful - Copyright (c) 2020 Serhii Kulykov iamkulykov@gmail.com (MIT license).